# Update mysql record and pass id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My form is:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" method="post">
                            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM prekes WHERE pirkejo_id=' . $pirkejas . '';
                            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                            $prekes = array();
                            foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                if ($row['prek_pav'] != '') {
                                    array_push($prekes, $row);
                                }
                            }?>                               
<input name="prekes[1][pavadinimas]" type="text" value="<?php echo $prekes[0]['prek_pav']?>">
<input name="prekes[1][kaina]" type="text" value="<?php echo $prekes[0]['prek_kaina'] ?>">
<input name="prekes[2][pavadinimas]" type="text"value="<?php echo $prekes[1]['prek_pav']?>">
<input name="prekes[2][kaina]" type="text" value="<?php echo $prekes[1]['prek_kaina'] ?>">
```

I dont know how to optimize it. I want to update my records in database and have no idea how to pass prekes_id value to UPDATE sql.
I found that My update updates all records with the last value from my form. all recors are same as last entered.

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "UPDATE customers  set name = ?, pavarde = ?, ak = ?, numeris = ?  WHERE id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($name, $pavarde, $ak, $numeris, $id));
    foreach ($prekes as $preke) {
    $sql = "UPDATE prekes SET prek_pav= ?,prek_kaina=? WHERE prekes_id=".$preke['prekes_id'];
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($preke['pavadinimas'], $preke['kaina']));
    }
    Database::disconnect();
    header("Location: default.php");
```

I use this `code` to solve this. Are there any better working solution to this problem?
My table prekes (prekes_id, pirkejo_id, prek_pav, prek_kaina). I take pirkejo_id from $_POST['id'].

Comment: Add a hidden field to the form with the record_id in it?

Comment: How to do that? 
I was thinking about an array with only prekes_id values, but i get problems in foreach loop.

Comment: My bad. You put the Id in the $_GET array ($_GET['id']) as it is part of the URL.  the $_POST array only contains the form field input. Ignore my 'add hidden field' comment as i did not read your question hard enough.